# How to add multi dimensional IloRangeArray to the model on CPLEX

Tags: c++, model, constraints, cplex, multi-dimensional-scaling

I'm a beginner in CPLEx and using it to wite my mathematical model. 
I defined and built a three dimensional IloRangeArray as my constraint as follows:

```
typedef IloArray<IloArray<IloRangeArray>> ThreeDimRange;
con = IloArray <IloArray <IloRangeArray> > (env, n);
for () 
{
    con [h] = IloArray <IloRangeArray> (env, nbRow);
    for ()
    {
        con[h][m] = IloRangeArray (env);
        for () 
        {
            IloExpr tempExp(env); 
            if ()
                 con [h][m].add(0 <= tempExp <= 0);
        }
    }
}
```

When I want to add "con" to the model (model.add(con);), I have the following error:

error C2664: 'IloExtractable IloModel::add(const IloExtractable) const' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'ThreeDimRange' to 'const IloExtractable'

It is the same for 2 dim IloArrangeArray. 
What is your opinion?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! It seems that though we have a multi-dimensional vector of IloRangeArray , we have to add each IloRangeArray seperately to the model.

```
typedef IloArray<IloArray<IloRangeArray>> ThreeDimRange;
con = IloArray <IloArray <IloRangeArray> > (env, n);
for () 
{
    con [h] = IloArray <IloRangeArray> (env, nbRow);
    for ()
    {
        con[h][m] = IloRangeArray (env);
        for () 
        {
            IloExpr tempExp(env); 
            if ()
                 con [h][m].add(0 <= tempExp <= 0);
        }
        **model.add(con[h][m]);**
    }
}
```